# Ignored parameter in for-comprehension for cats.data.WriterT

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I'm going through scala with cats. In the example of `Writer` ($4.7.2, p. 111) the following for-comprehension is used:

```
import cats.data.Writer
import cats.syntax.writer._
import cats.syntax.applicative._
import cats.instances.vector._
type Logged[A] = Writer[Vector[String], A]

val writer1 = for {
  a <- 10.pure[Logged]
  _ <- Vector("a", "b", "c").tell
  b <- 32.writer(Vector("x", "y", "z"))
} yield a + b
// writer1: cats.data.WriterT[cats.Id,Vector[String],Int] = WriterT((
Vector(a, b, c, x, y, z),42))
```

From what I know underscore (`_`) is used for ignored parameters, it is never used after `yield` keyword. Still values `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"` are written to the log. Is it an idiom or is there another explanation for that?

Comment: So `tell` is like printing a log, it has a return value of **Unit** you do not care about that, but still, the side effect occurred. In this case, instead of modifying the global standard output stream, the log of events that are kept inside the monad was modified _(in a copy of-course)_ and thus the final result has those values in the log. - Remember, the idea of monads is to manage effects in an easier way, a **Writer[L, A]** is a computation that produces values of type `A` while writing a log of type `L`; Thus, `flatMap` will just give you the composition of values and managing the log.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you very much, the side effect of `tell` was getting me. But doesn't it contradict the functional paradigm?

Comment: Not, because in this case is not a _side_ effect, just an effect. We know by the type that those values are producing some log, also those values are pure, if you call them twice you get two identical but yet different logs, so unlike println that would modify a mutable buffer, you can refactor them freely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Writer` monad can be thought of as a tuple where the first element represents log value whilst the second element represents the main business value. The key is to understand that the underscore `_` in

```
for {
  a <- 10.pure[Logged]
  _ <- Vector("a", "b", "c").tell
  b <- 32.writer(Vector("x", "y", "z"))
} yield a + b
```

stands for the "business value", that is, the second `._2` element of the tuple, and not the entire tuple, so only the business value is ignored at this point in the composition. Perhaps it would help if we de-sugared the for-comprehension

```
WriterT[Id, Vector[String], Int](Vector(), 10).flatMap { (a: Int) =>
  WriterT[Id, Vector[String], Unit](Vector("a", "b", "c"), ()).flatMap { (_: Unit) =>
    WriterT[Id, Vector[String], Int](Vector("x", "y", "z"), 32).map { (b: Int) =>
      a + b
    }
  }
}
```

In this way we see nothing really unusual is happening; the argument `(_: Unit)` is simply not being used in the body of `(_: Unit) => body`. Now lets also have a look under the hood of `flatMap`

```
def flatMap[U](
  f: V => WriterT[F, L, U]
)(implicit flatMapF: FlatMap[F], semigroupL: Semigroup[L]): WriterT[F, L, U] =
  WriterT {
    flatMapF.flatMap(run) { lv =>
      flatMapF.map(f(lv._2).run) { lv2 =>
        (semigroupL.combine(lv._1, lv2._1), lv2._2)
      }
    }
  }
```

Few things immediately pop

- tuple notation `._1` and `._2`
- `semigroupL.combine(lv._1, lv2._1)`
- `f(lv._2)`

We see how semigroup is used to combine logs which are first elements of tuples. Analysing `f(lv._2)` in our case we have `lv._2 = ()` and `f` is function `(_: Unit) => body` where the argument `(_: Unit)` is simply not being used in the `body`.

In general the particular definition of `flatMap` is what gives monads their characteristic power. In the case of `Writer` this power allows it to transparently combine logs as we progress along the chain of computations.

---

As a side note, as Luis says, there is no *side*-effect happening here. Consider the functional programming sense of the term *effect* in the following sentences

```
 - Identity monad encodes the effect of having no effect
 - IO       monad encodes the effect of having a side-effect
 - Option   monad encodes the effect of having optionality
```

The semantics of effect are encoded by the implementation of `flatMap`.